# Update a Table by Passing Table Name, ColumnName as a Variable Using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, variables, sql-update

I want to Update a Table. I am getting Table Name and Column Name as a XML DataSet from the Front End. I have written One Cursor for that. But it throws error. Below is my Cursor

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PMT_Formstatus_Update_Test]
(
@XMLTableNames VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @docHandle INT, @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(200), @doc VARCHAR(200)
    SET @doc = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>'

    DECLARE @Names TABLE
(   
        TName VARCHAR(50),
    CName VARCHAR(50),
    IDField VARCHAR(50),
    FunctionID INT,
    ID INT,             
    StatusID INT
    )
    SET @XMLTableNames = @doc + @XMLTableNames          
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT,  @XMLTableNames
    INSERT INTO @Names
    SELECT * FROM 
        OPENXML(@docHandle,'NewDataSet/NameDetails',2)
            WITH
            (
                TName VARCHAR(50),
                CName VARCHAR(50),
                IDField VARCHAR(50),
                FunctionID INT,
                ID INT,
                StatusID INT
                            )

    DECLARE @FunctionID INT
DECLARE @StatusID INT
DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @IDField VARCHAR(50)

    DECLARE @getTables CURSOR
    SET @getTables = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT FunctionID, TName, CName, StatusID, IDField, ID FROM @Names
    OPEN @getTables
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getTables INTO @FunctionID, @TableName, @ColumnName, @StatusID, @IDField, @ID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    UPDATE @TableName SET @ColumnName = 3 WHERE @IDField = @ID
        FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getTables INTO @FunctionID, @TableName, @ColumnName, @StatusID, @IDField, @ID
    END

    CLOSE @getTables
    DEALLOCATE @getTables
END
```

How to write Update Query in this case? Please I need all your suggestions...

Comment: Why do you need/want to do that?

Comment: Actually, I am getting all the above variables as a xml dataset from the Front End. Based on the Values I want to Update the Corresponding Tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate them as string then call `EXEC('')`

`EXEC ('UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName1 = 3 WHERE ColumnName2= Value')`

Answer (score 1):

Simple Dynamic SQL Example:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max),@TableName VARCHAR(128),@ColumnName1 VARCHAR(128),@ColumnName2 VARCHAR(128),@Value NVARCHAR(MAX),@NewValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TableName='User'
SET @ColumnName1='Session_Id'
SET @ColumnName2='Session_Id_Old'
SET @Value=''''+CAST(NEWID() as NVARCHAR(50))+''''
SET @NewValue=''''+CAST(NEWID() as NVARCHAR(50))+''''

SET @SQL=
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
'UPDATE [@TableName] SET [@ColumnName1] = @NewValue WHERE [@ColumnName2]= @Value','@TableName',@TableName),
'@ColumnName1',@ColumnName1),'@Value',@Value),'@NewValue',@NewValue),'@ColumnName2',@ColumnName2)
        EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

You should add apostrophes to both sides of old/new values if data types are strings

Answer (score 1):

You can hopefully see why what you've written doesn't work, since it's an update statement to execute against a table variable, which affects no actual columns in that table:

```
declare @TableName table (ID int not null)
declare @ColumnName1 int
declare @ColumnName2 int
declare @Value int
UPDATE @TableName SET @ColumnName1 = 3 WHERE @ColumnName2= @Value
```

One means to try and achieve what you're doing are dynamic SQL. It's ugly (and will be more so if the data types in the columns vary). There's no real "meta-programming" system built into T-SQL.